# Is this standard SharePoint Designer behaviour?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I've been picking up on some very weird behaviour in SharePoint Designer (2007) lately that's been bugging me. Don't really know what to Google for but most of the feedback I got is around caching:

Basically, when we connect to a site through Designer, it brings back a list of all directories as expected, but the expected "icons" are all just normal folder icons, not the unique icons for master pages, etc. that you would normally expect.

Is this standard behaviour for the designer to loose it's marbles completely, and would the only alternate solution be to clear the cache for designer?

Thanks,

Eric